# How do i compare two dictionaries in swift and then append any similarities to a new dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, sorting, dictionary

i know this might seem like a confusing question so here's my scenario... I have two dictionaries and i need to organise them into one dictionary where the keys from both of the initial 2 dictionaries share the same values from the keys that are the same from the starting 2 dictionaries. Example:

```
var dict1 = [1: "fruit", 2: "vegetable", 3: "meat"]
var dict2 = [2: "carrot", 3: "steak", 1: "apple", 3: "pork"] 
var newDict = [1: ["fruit": ["apple"]], 2: ["vegetable": ["carrot"]], 3: ["meat": ["steak, pork"]]]
```

So its organised where each category (fruit, veg, meat) has a unique id (Int), and in that category is an array of values appropriate for that category. The end result is that i'm hoping to populate a table view with this data using the category's as section headers and the array of values for that sections data.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You have an issue with your initial data, `dict2` is not a valid dictionary because you have duplicate keys.

Comment: But i don't get any errors?

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a try. I was probably just overthinking it. :)

Comment: @EricAya "having an Int as a dictionary key doesn't make much sense, better use an array (indexed) in that case." True, but what if the key is number 1, 18, 100201, etc. I mean they have no relation to a *sequence*. I don't know of a good use case but I'm just countering for a rare edge case :D

Comment: @Honey If the int key has a meaning, if it represents something, why not. If it's just an index as in OP's question then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The main problem was i was converting some JSON to make a food database, and the JSON was structured so it would have lets say 5 categories and those categories would have unique id's (Int's), and then you would have the food that is supposed to link up with the categories that is structured in a similar way so each individual food would have a unique id (int) which would be equal to one of the food categories id. And i was extracting the JSON from two seperate files and storing the foods into one dictionary and the categories in another with the appropriate id's.

Comment: And then the plan was to merge the two into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your code does not compile

As *@Bogdan Farca* noted in the comments your second dictionary won't compile because of duplicate key

```
let dict2 = [2: "carrot", 3: "steak", 1: "apple", 3: "pork"]
```

[image]

A better way to represent the information of `dict2` is using the **food name** as `key` and the **category ID** as `value`

```
let dict2 = ["carrot" : 2,"steak": 2,"apple": 1, "pork":3]
```

> I am assuming the food names to be unique.

### Better names

In order to make the code more readable we should also use better names so

```
let categories = [1: "fruit", 2: "vegetable", 3: "meat"]
let foods = ["carrot" : 2, "steak": 3, "apple": 1, "pork":3]
```

### Using a Model

We can finally focus on the solution.
You want as output something like this `[Int : Dictionary<String, Array<String>>]`

It's a complex combination of dictionaries/arrays, why don't you simply use a model value?

```
struct FoodCategory {
    let categoryID: Int
    let categoryName: String
    let foods: [String]
}
```

Now you can just write

```
let foodCategories = categories.map { cat -> FoodCategory in
    let foodNames = foods.filter { $0.value == cat.key }.map { $0.0 }
    return FoodCategory(categoryID: cat.key, categoryName: cat.value, foods: foodNames )
}
```

And this is the result

```
[
    FoodCategory(categoryID: 2, categoryName: "vegetable", foods: ["carrot"]),
    FoodCategory(categoryID: 3, categoryName: "meat", foods: ["pork", "steak"]),
    FoodCategory(categoryID: 1, categoryName: "fruit", foods: ["apple"])
]
```

Comment: You've really helped. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, your second dictionary has duplicate keys, so it's not valid Swift.

Assuming you solve the duplicate key issue by replacing the duplicate with a new one, unique this time, here is a quick algorithm almost achieving what you want.

```
let dict1 = [1: "fruit", 2: "vegetable", 3: "meat"]
let dict2 = [2: "carrot", 3: "steak", 1: "apple", 4: "pork"]

var newDict = [Int:[String:[String]]]()

for category in dict1 {
    if let existingCat = newDict[category.key] {

    } else {
        let newCat = [category.value: [dict2[category.key]!]]
        newDict[category.key] = newCat
    }
}

print (newDict)
```

It won't give you the list of products you want though, so I've changed your input data types to something more suitable (I'm not saying it's optimal, but it works):

```
let input1 = [(1, "fruit"), (2, "vegetable"), (3, "meat")]
let input2 = [(2, "carrot"), (3, "steak"), (1, "apple"), (3, "pork")]

var newDict = [Int:[String:[String]]]()

for category in input1 {
    newDict[category.0] = [category.1:[]]
}

for meal in input2 {
    if let existingCat = newDict[meal.0]?.first {
        newDict[meal.0] = [existingCat.key: existingCat.value + [meal.1]]
    }
}

print (newDict)
```

At the end `newDict`prints:

```
[2: ["vegetable": ["carrot"]], 3: ["meat": ["steak", "pork"]], 1: ["fruit": ["apple"]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you correct your dictionaries to:

```
let dict1 = [1: "fruit", 2: "vegetable", 3: "meat"]
var dict2 = [2: ["carrot"], 1: ["apple"], 3: ["pork", "steak"]]
```

you could reduce it with

```
let result = dict1.keys.reduce([Int: [String: [String]]]()) { (result, key) in
    var result = result
    result.updateValue([dict1[key]!: dict2[key] ?? []], forKey: key)
    return result
}
```

which would result in `[2: ["vegetable": ["carrot"]], 3: ["meat": ["pork", "steak"]], 1: ["fruit": ["apple"]]]`

Answer (score 0):

This may be help for you

```
 var dict1 = [(0, ["sender": "user1", "time": NSDate(), "mId": "as2f2ASf"]), (1, ["sender": "user1", "time": NSDate(), "mId": "Sjf82FsJ"])]

 var dict2 = [(0, ["sender": "user2", "time": NSDate(), "mId": "J2fAS92D"]), (1, ["sender": "user2", "time": NSDate(), "mId": "Sjf82FsJ"])]


var dict3 = [[0: ["sender": "user1", "time": NSDate(), "mId": "as2f2ASf"]], [1: ["sender": "user1", "time": NSDate(), "mId": "Sjf82FsJ"]]]for (_,value1) in dict1 {


 if let mld1 = value1["mId"] {
for(_,value2) in dict2 {
  if let mld2 = value2["mId"] {
    if mld1 == mld2 {
      println("Found diff")
    }
  }
}
 }
}
```